# Is it possible to access sonarqube analysis results in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

As per the sonar logs, I see that sonar first runs the sensors, then the decorators and then stores the analysis results to the database. Is is possible to access analysis results in a sonar plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem here.
http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Where-can-I-find-new-issue-information-on-sonar-db-td5021022.html

```
// this annotation is important to be sure that relevant data on issues are up-to-date.
@DependsUpon(DecoratorBarriers.ISSUES_TRACKED)
public final class MyDecorator implements Decorator {
  private final ResourcePerspectives perspectives;

  public TechnicalDebtDecorator(ResourcePerspectives perspectives) {
    this.perspectives = perspectives;
  }

  public void decorate(Resource resource, DecoratorContext context) {
    Issuable issuable = perspectives.as(Issuable.class, resource);
    if (issuable != null) {
      List<Issue> issues = issuable.issues();
      // Issue has method isNew()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sonar web application is available at localhost:9000 (or wherever it's installed).

There is also a plugin for Eclipse to view issues:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question here.

I am thinking of a plugin here which uses the results on the current analysis and does operations on them.

So, the question was, can that be done? Is it feasible at all?